# Why is my nth-child selector selecting the wrong element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors, noscript

I have this element tree (stolen from Stack Overflow's 404 page):

[image]

When we look at it, the highlighted `<div>` is supposed to be the fourth element. However, doing `$('body > div:nth-child(4)')` returns the div before. Why is this so? Is is somehow selecting the div in the `<noscript>` tag? When I remove the `<noscript>`, it selects properly.

[image]

Why is it behaving like that?

Comment: Try adding a `class` or `id` to that `div`

Comment: Does nth-child(1) return the noscript div?

Comment: No, I don't think so, because your no-script is on top of your divs.

Comment: What is expected result ? Which `div` attemptig to select ? `div` following `div#custom-header` ?

Comment: why not look for $('body > div:nth-child(1)') ?

Comment: @dman2306 :nth-child(1) returns nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div:nth-child(4)` does not give you the 4th `div`, it gives you the element that is both a `div` and a 4th child (and gives you nothing if the 4th child is something that is not a div; that is why you are not getting anything for `div:nth-child(1)`). The 4th div that you want is the 5th child with `<noscript>` present, and 4th child without it.

From jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

> The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-class is easily confused with `:eq(n)`, even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With `:eq(n)` only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

So, if you want the 4th `div`, you will do `body > div:eq(3)`.

Comment: Is jQuery not capable of selecting children of `noscript` element ?

Comment: @guest271314: Of course it is, with `body > noscript > div` or `body div`. Not with `body > div`, as that `div` is a *grandchild* of `body`, not a child, so it would not show up with the "direct descendant" `>` operator.

Comment: _"Of course it is, with `body > noscript > div`"_ Interestingly , children of `noscript` appear set as text node , not `div` element  http://jsfiddle.net/52grpf7L/3/

Answer (score 1):

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039966/jquery-difference-between-eq-and-nth-child)

#### [Step 1]

**:nth-child()**

> Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.
>
> jQuery's implementation of :nth-child(n) is strictly derived from the CSS specification

**W3C specification** [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

> The :nth-child(*a*n+*b*) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has *a*n+*b*-1 siblings before it in the document tree

So here `:nth-child(4)` present the full form `:nth-child(0n+4)`, and denote an element has exactly **3 siblings before it in the document tree**

**noscript tag**

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272457/does-noscript-get-acknowledged-by-javascript-enabled-browsers)

If enabled javascript, The `<noscript>` tag may not be rendered but can still accessed using `nextSibling` or `prevSibling`, so it's counting with `nth-child`

#### [Step 2]

`body > div` is combined with `:nth-child` just like other  **pseudo-classes** , e.g. `a:hover` and `tr:hover`, the `:hover` is not concern whether it's a `a` or `tr` tag, just a **special selector**

#### [The Whole Thing]

`body>div:nth-child(4)` first select `body>div`, and then select the **div** which has exactly **3** siblings before it, so the `<noscript>` tag counting.

Answer (score -3):

Try Changing `div:nth-child(4)` to `div:nth-child(5)` I've tested It and It works with 5th child not 4th child. With the 4th child It selects the `<div>` before the one you want.

Comment: It is a trivial solution; the OP is not asking how to select a `div` when the numbering is one off from what he expects (it is obvious), but *why* the numbering is not as he expects.

Comment: @Arqetech The asker knows this, and knows that adding +1 to the selector would work. But that's not what he's asking about.